# Calculus of Variations Problem with a differential equation : $X'(t)=-aX(t)E(t)$

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations, optimal-control

We define the following Calculus of Variations problem :

$\max \int_0^1[X(t)E(t)-c(E(t))]dt$ subjetct to $X(0)=1000$ $X(1)=500$

and $X'(t)=-aX(t)E(t)$ (and $a$ is a constant). with the hypothesis that $c$ is a continuous and convex function of $E$.

I tried to write it as a Calculus of Variations problems :

$\max \int_0^1[-aX'(t)-c(-a\frac{X'(t)}{X(t)})]dt$ subjetct to $X(0)=1000$ $X(1)=500$

And I'm stuck on proving that this problem has a solution (existence).

(Note that we are looking for $E(t)$ )

Comment: What does $E(t)$ represent? A function? Also, do you know the Euler-Lagrange equations?

Comment: is a function of $t$, Yeah but Euler equations gives a necessary condition. it doesn't answer the question of existence.